# Commutation behavior of spinors in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, commutator, spinors, scattering-cross-section

I am currently playing around with computing cross sections of several simple interactions in QED like Bhabha and Compton Scattering and I have stumbled upon a question which I havent yet managed to resolve myself.

**The situation at hand:**

Let us consider the spin averaged sum of the t-channels' squared S-matrix in Compton Scattering. According to [Section 1.3 in this source](https://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/QFT/PicsII/QFT10Mar05Bhabha.pdf) it can be computed as:

[image]

As in every computation of spin averaged matrix elements we now make use of spinor- or polarization vector completeness relations by moving the spinors such that we can pair them and make use of an expression like:

$ \sum_s u(\mathbf{p}, s) \bar{u}(\mathbf{p}, s)=\not p+m \\ $ 
$ \sum_s v(\mathbf{p}, s) \bar{v}(\mathbf{p}, s)=\not p-m $

As you can see this has been done in the second line of aboves equation where spinors and respective adjoint spinors have been paired up. This total operation has caused a factor of $(-1)^{14}$ which is the core of my question:

**My question**

Since I cannot commute spinors past gamma matrices, how is the operation that happened between those two lines justified? Also, where does the prefactor with the 14th power come from?

Comment: The *components* of $u$, $\bar{u}$, ect. and the *matrix elements* of the gamma matrices are *c-numbers*. You do not get a factor $-1$ when you interchange any of them. You are confusing these objects with the fermionic *field operators*, which have however disappeared already at this point of the calculation.

Comment: If that is the case, how do you explain the factor of (-1)^14 in the source and also, if the order is completely irrelevant why is it important to write down the Feynman rules of each diagram in the ,,correct order“?

Comment: There is nothing to "explain" about a factor $(-1)^{14}=1$. Your second point has nothing to do with the first.